# blend one color into another

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

I am made a flower with five petals which is one object. I want the inside center of the flower colored white then fade to a light pink on the outside petals. I can do some of the basics with the nodes but not sure how to mix two RGB to blend from the inside to the outside. As you can see I did have a start with the nodes but don't know how to make it all work. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Add gradient texture (spherical) and plug it in MixRGB factor

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I might be connecting these up wrong but not getting the effect I was looking for. Maybe more details would be of help.

Answer (score 1):

UV unwrap your mesh as *Project from view* (I did it from top view).
To put gradient in center, use a gradient texture node, add *Mapping node* and modify X,Y coordinates. You can use *ColorRamp node* for better control of color blending.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to show me how to do this. I never thought of using the UV unwrapping for this purpose. This will be helpful for other projects.

Comment: Just wanted to add for the sake of others who google this. Your node structure is incorrect. You should have the MixRGB between the color outputs of the Coloramp and Diffuse BSDF. In the node setup that you show, the MixRGB has no control over the visible output.